# Change in day only

Tags: google-bigquery

```
date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") > "2018-03-27 15:00:00"
```

is a criterion to pull the data in a query which I run daily. So basically, I want the only day to change daily but rest things same.
Can anyone help?

```
SELECT 
a.order as Order_Number,unique(b.status_name) as Status, 
date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") as Ordered_Date, 
date_add(a.Export_date,4,"Hour") as Exported_Date, 
date_add(a.Dispatch_date,4,"Hour") as Dispatched_Date 
FROM 
[ops_views.Order_Timeline] as a 
left join [ops_views.sales_order_item] as b 
ON a.Order=b.order_nr 
WHERE 
LEFT(a.Order,2)="AE" AND 
date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") > "2018-03-26 15:00:00" AND 
date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") <= "2018-03-27 15:00:00" and 
b.status_name not in ("test_invalid","invalid","canceled","canceled_exportable") 
GROUP BY 1,3,4,5,
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to all your questions.

Comment: SELECT
 a.order as Order_Number,unique(b.status_name) as Status, date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") as Ordered_Date, date_add(a.Export_date,4,"Hour") as Exported_Date, date_add(a.Dispatch_date,4,"Hour") as Dispatched_Date
FROM
 [ops_views.Order_Timeline] as a
 left join [ops_views.sales_order_item] as b
 on a.Order=b.order_nr
WHERE
 LEFT(a.Order,2)="AE"
 AND date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") > "2018-03-26 15:00:00" and date_add(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") <= "2018-03-27 15:00:00" and b.status_name not in ("test_invalid","invalid","canceled","canceled_exportable")
 GROUP BY 1,3,4,5,

Answer (score 2):

so, if (for example) you need to filter data for time period between 3pm yesterday and 3pm day before yesterday - you can use something like below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
AND DATE_ADD(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") > 
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d 15:00:00', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) 
AND DATE_ADD(a.Order_date,4,"Hour") <= 
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d 15:00:00', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```